# How to check value of a column lies between values of two columns in other file and print corresponding value from column in Unix?

Tags: unix, awk

I have two files to be compared. I found how to compare columns and print according to condition. My problem at hand is that I have to check if the value of column[2] in file1 lies between value in file2 defined as a range in two columns, col [2] col[3]. If that is true, then I should print column[4] of file 2 in my file1.

#### file1:

```
scaffold1_size11    12
scaffold2_size22    26
scaffold3_size33    67
```

#### file2:

```
scaffold1_size11    1   10  Os01
scaffold1_size11    12  20  Os08
scaffold1_size11    29  59  Os07
scaffold2_size22    17  24  Os09
scaffold2_size22    27  38  Os09
scaffold2_size22    39  60  Os10
scaffold2_size22    67  78  Os10
scaffold3_size33    15  27  Os03
scaffold3_size33    29  62  Os08
scaffold3_size33    64  78  Os02
scaffold3_size33    80  98  Os01
```

#### desired output:

```
scaffold1_size11    12  Os08
scaffold2_size22    26
scaffold3_size33    67  Os02
```

How should this be done?

Comment: "the i should print column[2] of file 2 in my file1." Unclear; please supply the desired output for this particular example.

Comment: i have reviewed my question with desired output.

Comment: Please check the desired output for `scaffold2_size22`; there should be a third value (of `Os09`) there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a standard idiom in `awk` which uses `FNR` (file record number) and `NR` (overall record number) to detect when you're reading the first file.  You read and save the values of the first file in arrays, and then use the arrays while reading the second file.

In this context, you want to read `file1` first, saving the records based on the value in column 1 (`$1`).  This assumes that the keys in `file1` (the first field) are unique.  Then, when reading the second file,

```
awk 'FNR == NR { val[$1] = $2 }
     FNR != NR { if ($1 in val && val[$1] >= $2 && val[$1] <= $3)
                     print $1, val[$1], $4
               }' file1 file2
```

Sample output:

```
scaffold1_size11 12 Os08
scaffold2_size22 26 Os09
scaffold3_size33 67 Os02
```

Note that this is different from the sample output in the question, which is:

```
scaffold1_size11    12  Os08
scaffold2_size22    26
scaffold3_size33    67  Os02
```

I assume that's a typo in the question since none of the rows in `file2` is missing the fourth column.

You'll also see the idiom used like:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { …save…; next }
     { …process… }'
```

The `next` skips the second block of code while reading the first file.  It might be marginally more efficient, but I tend to like the explicit clarity of the two inverted conditions.

If spacing in the output is an issue, use an appropriate `printf` statement in place of the `print`.

Comment: yes, there is a typo. Actually, there is also a situation in which assignment of any Os to file1 goes empty. To include that condition also i gave that as desired output.

Comment: You didn't give any indication whatsoever about how that special condition arises.  That makes it a bad idea to include it in the expected output.  Either explain exactly what you want, including the wrinkles, or show the simple-minded output ignoring the wrinkles that you can (and should) deal with after you have the basic mechanism in place.

Comment: sorry for the error in typing, i have now included that condition too in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shell script that does what you want. It uses awk to tranform file2 into another awk script (tmp.awk), which in turn filters file1.

```
awk '{ a[$1] = a[$1] "$2 >= " $2 " && $2 <= " $3 " ? \"" $4 "\" : "; } END { for (i in a) print "$1 == \"" i "\" { print $0 \"\\t\" (" a[i] "\"\"); }"; }' file2 > tmp.awk
awk -f tmp.awk file1
```

Notes:

- Duplicate lines in file1 result in duplicate lines in the output. If necessary, pipe the result to `uniq` or `sort -u`.
- This approach is based on the presumption that typically, file2 will be relatively small (compared to a potentially large file1); if not, then this approach may suffer from bad performance.