# how can I make awk match up lines in file 1 with the lines in file 2 based on some number ranges in file 2

Tags: linux, awk, scripting

I have the following two files:

file 1:

```
22
2
42
32
```

file 2:

```
1 10 valuea
11 20 valueb
21 30 valuec
31 40 valued
41 50 valuee
51 60 valuef
```

How can I make awk grab each value from file 1, match it up with file 2 based on whether it falls between the number range in columns 1 and 2 of file 2, and then print out column 3 from the matched column in file 2? The output would resemble the following:

```
valuec
valuea
valuee
valued
```

I tried using the following AWK command (based on what I found in this post: [How to check value of a column lies between values of two columns in other file and print corresponding value from column in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608870/how-to-check-value-of-a-column-lies-between-values-of-two-columns-in-other-file)), but it does not seem to be working correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'FNR == NR { val[$1] = $1 }
     FNR != NR { if (val[$1] >= $1 && val[$1] <= $2)
                     print $3
               }' file1 file2
```

Also I did not include it in here for obvious reasons, but for the actual application of this script, file 1 would include around 7,000 entries while file 2 would include 68,000 entries

Comment: does it haveto be awk ? would you be content with using comm ?

Comment: @louigi600 yep, comm is perfectly fine

Comment: Ok I'll write that as an answer ... you could ack it as a usefull answer ... it will help with my reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative `awk` script

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1]=$2; v[$1]=$3; next} 
                 {for(k in a) 
                      if(k+0<=$1 && $1+0<=a[k]) print v[k]}' file2 file1

valuec
valuea
valuee
valued
```

note that file2 is the first file.  This will cover multiple range matches as well. `+0` is to force for numerical comparison.